# How to wait for data on a COM port

Tags: c++, visual-c++, serial-port

I am using .Net framework's SerialPort class (System.IO.Ports) and am trying to wait to receive data. I've looked around and the WaitCommEvent function seems to be what people suggest using, however it expects a HANDLE as the first parameter. I would like to know either how to get a handle from the SerialPort or a different way to wait for data compatible with the SerialPort class.

Comment: CreateFile with the name of the comm port as a parameter should give you a handle.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you read the [`SerialPort` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx), you would see that it has a [DataReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx) event: "*Indicates that data has been received through a port represented by the SerialPort object.*"

Comment: @Remy That's C++/CLI, not C++.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: So what? The OP says "*I am using .Net framework's SerialPort class*". It doesn't matter if C# or C++ or C++/CLI is used, the class operates the same, all that matters is the language syntax to assign an event handler.

Comment: @Remy The post is tagged C++. But feel free to re-tag it.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: The post is also tagged `visual-c++`, which includes C++/CLI.

Answer (score 0):

The [`SerialPort` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) has a [DataReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) event:

> Indicates that data has been received through a port represented by the SerialPort object.

The documentation provides the following C++/CLI example:

```
#using <System.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO::Ports;

ref class PortDataReceived
{
public:
    static void Main()
    {
        SerialPort^ mySerialPort = gcnew SerialPort("COM1");

        mySerialPort->BaudRate = 9600;
        mySerialPort->Parity = Parity::None;
        mySerialPort->StopBits = StopBits::One;
        mySerialPort->DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort->Handshake = Handshake::None;
        mySerialPort->RtsEnable = true;

        mySerialPort->DataReceived += gcnew SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        mySerialPort->Open();

        Console::WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console::WriteLine();
        Console::ReadKey();
        mySerialPort->Close();
    }

private:
    static void DataReceivedHandler(
                        Object^ sender,
                        SerialDataReceivedEventArgs^ e)
    {
        SerialPort^ sp = (SerialPort^)sender;
        String^ indata = sp->ReadExisting();
        Console::WriteLine("Data Received:");
        Console::Write(indata);
    }
};

int main()
{
    PortDataReceived::Main();
}
```